# Есть ли у XML нечто, что не может JSON? И есть ли у XML и JSON что-то, что не может CSV

Tags: python, json, xml, csv

Изучая в сравнении XML и JSON,
https://msiter.ru/tutorials/javascript/js_json_xml
https://itgap.ru/post/json-vs-xml-sravnenie-tekhnologij-i-oblasti-primeneniya
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp
https://habr.com/ru/post/31225/

обнаружил две вещи.

1. принципиальным преимуществом XML перед  JSON есть какие то "метаданные", и ни одного внятного примера "что и зачем" и в чем победа )). Вопрос №1 - есть ли что в XML, чего не сможет JSON. Ну и нормальный пример про это ))
2. все примеры наводят на мысль о том, что CSV будет получше обоих. [Например](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp):

[image: пример сравнения JSON и XML]

Намного короче и читабельнее будет CSV, с разделителем -табуляцией!!

```
firstName   lastName
John        Doe
Anna        Smith
Peter       Jones
```

Итого вопрос №2 - что могут XML и  JSON, чего не сможет CSV?

Comment: получше обоих в чем?

Comment: @azlov в наглядности и объеме памяти - то чем хвалится JSON  против XML

Comment: 1 - Насколько я помню, в xml можно создать рекурсивную структуру (внутренний узел будет ссылаться на внешний узел - хотя я не вижу в этом особого практического смысла), в json же можно реализовать только дерево. 2 - csv хорош только для двумерных таблиц. Дерево произвольной вложенности на нем не опишешь.

Comment: XML - это ещё и [XSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL). В JSON и тем более CSV нет ничего даже приблизительно схожего по функционалу. В JSON можно хранить объекты произвольной размерности, чего в CSV при всём желании не затолкать.

Comment: @insolor а можно пример?  ну или ссылку. спасибо за коммент !

Comment: Для xml есть развитая валидация, причём несколько разных схем. Впрочем, для json тоже уже давно есть схемы.

Comment: В xml и csv все значения только строки, например. В то время как в json бывают ещё числа, true, false, null. Ну и вообще у каждого формата своя область применимости

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### CSV

Очень не практичен.

Плюсы:

- можно открыть и отредактировать в Excel с уровнем подготовки "секретарша"
- в том же Excel можно сделать авто-фильтры и подготовить простую отчетность
- можно сделать импорт и экспорт в БД MySQL, у этой РСУБД есть для этого встроенные средства

Минусы:

- нет иерархии
- легаси - колонки: когда ваш CSV используется как выгрузка сотнями клиентов (обмен данными между системами), нельзя просто взять и удалить устаревшие колонки, все поедет

> CSV будет получше обоих

> Намного короче и читабельнее будет CSV, с разделителем -табуляцией

На совсем простых данных - возможно. Чуть усложните - и не будет преимуществ, а только одни недостатки.

> что могут XML и JSON, чего не сможет CSV

Снова: иерархия, и сложности при изменении структуры документа.

### JSON

Практичен.

Плюсы:

- иерархия
- schema-less

Минусы:

- не предусмотрены комментарии (которые предусмотрены в YAML)
- хуже читабельность, чем в YAML
- формат: только unicode

### XML

Плюсы:

- иерархия
- любая кодировка
- механизм проверки схемы на основе XSD
- киллер-фича: возможность преобразования в XHTML / HTML / другой XML документ на основе декларативного [XSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL) - очень мощная штука
- ссылки на другие части документа

Минусы:

- многословность

### YAML

Добавил и про этот формат, для полной картины.

Плюсы:

- комментарии
- минималистичность
- ссылки на другие части документа
- возможность задания типа

Минусы: не могу указать, но конечно, они есть.

### Что может XML, а не может JSON

В принципе, возможности сильно совпадают, либо в JSON "дорабатываются" путем программирования. Почему [JSON лучше](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp):

- XML труднее парсить
- JSON парсится в JS объект, готовый к использованию

Что нельзя в JSON:

#### 1. Делать трансформацию документа через XSLT

было:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Offices>
  <Office id="4">
    <PersTitle>Москва</PersTitle>
  </Office>
</Offices>
```

стало:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companies>
  <company>
    <company-id>4</company-id>
    <shortname lang="ru">Офис Москва</shortname>
  </company>
</companies>
```

Трансформация осуществляется через [XSLT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), в виде декларативного синтаксиса, его я не привел, это целая наука. По сути это - шаблонизатор, встроенный, и очень мощный, не зависящий от языка программирования.

Ровно таким способом превращают XML в читаемый браузером HTML. С JSON придется использовать шаблонизатор или программировать.

#### 2. Делать валидацию через XSD

Есть встроенный механизм валидации [XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) на основе декларативного систаксиса. С JSON придется программировать.

#### 3. Делать ссылки на другие части

Делается через [XPointer](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp). С JSON придется программировать.

#### 4. Кодировка

Она важна, если приложение работает с несколькими системами, и не все понимают unicode. Часто какая-то система выдает документ в однобайтной кодировке, например cp1251, и просто нет выбора.

### Пример: почему JSON/XML лучше CSV

Допустим, на сайте сделали выгрузку для партнеров: артикул-количество.

Все партнеры запрограммировали свои системы на такой формат.

Затем бизнес сказал: давайте удалим количество, будем выдавать ранг: 0 - нет на складе, ..., 10 - полная доступность.

В CSV придется делать третий столбец, а что писать во второй? Допустим, 0. Так и застрянет этот 0 в выгрузке.

С JSON/XML - написали новое поле, старое - удалили, у партнеров сломался импорт, они посмотрели почему - и поправили у себя. А с CSV у них так и будет 0 продукции, пока не заметят менеджеры.

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, это ответ. А можно пример того, что может XML, а не может JSON?
Ну прям с тегами, структурой и объяснением?  Ну или ссылку на это?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, дополнил в секции "Что может XML, а не может JSON"

Comment: *"Она важна, если приложение работает с несколькими системами, и не все понимают unicode."* -- можно пример системы, не понимающей UTF-8?

Comment: `"json ... только unicode"` - с чего это вдруг? Я не вижу препятствий в том чтобы на отдающей стороне кодировать в любую кодировку, на принимающей декодировать, потом десериализовать. Единственно, отдающая и принимающая сторона должны как-то заранее договориться об используемой кодировке.

Comment: @dIm0n, innsolor, есть системы, которые вы не можете изменить. Например, банковский сектор энтерпрайза. Вы вынуждены следовать тем форматам, какие они используют, и кодировкам, на которых они работают.

Comment: @insolor, `Я не вижу препятствий в том чтобы на отдающей стороне кодировать в любую кодировку, на принимающей декодировать` - энтерпрайзные приложения вам не подвластны

Comment: @insolor `"json ... только unicode" - с чего это вдруг?` - так по стандарту. `JSON syntax describes a sequence of Unicode code points` [Стандарт](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

Comment: @TotalPusher, ок, по поводу стандарта - допустим. Но чисто технически json в каком-нибудь cp1251 вполне возможен, хоть и не очень практичен) По поводу банковского или госсектора - если у них есть какой-то стандарт, то и выбор между csv/json/xml не стоит, если установят ТФФ формат использовать с разделением палками (как TXPP для платежных поручений) - значит других вариантов нет) А у себя (для хранения настроек например) хоть JSONC используй - никто ничего не скажет)

Comment: @TotalPusher  -  вот за это я и люблю Python - сообщество. За предустановленную доброжелательность ))

Answer (score 5):

`CSV` удобнее только в том случае, когда у вас табличные данные - строго прямоугольные по форме (например, только числовые либо короткие текстовые поля, обязательные для всех записей). А если у вас сильно вложенные структуры, да с разным числом элементов, какие-то поля есть, каких-то нет, да плюс ещё в данных длинные строки разной длины, то все преимущества `CSV` сходят на нет, потому что у вас либо "поедет" вся красота, либо вам придётся отводить под столбцы место какого-то гигантского размера, чтобы уместилось самое длинное значение и вы будете бесконечно скроллировать данные, чтобы посмотреть что-то в дальних столбцах. И это всё-равно не решит проблему сильной вложенности разного кол-ва элементов.

`JSON` с данными разной длины и вложенности будет выглядеть гораздо нагляднее.

Насчёт `XML` ничего не скажу - сам его не люблю, за избыточность разметки.
Хотя вот @Insolor правильно дополнил в комментариях, что в принципе `XML` может ссылаться на собственные элементы, а в `JSON` вы не можете несколько раз сослаться на один и тот же элемент в разных местах, вам придётся повторять его каждый раз. Поэтому `XML` часто используют для конфигураций.

Comment: "в JSON вы не можете несколько раз сослаться на один и тот же элемент в разных местах" - но стоит помнить, что JSON это просто структура данных, в мы с вам всё же программисты

Comment: то есть речь о том, что программист не в состоянии обработать данные и разбить их в нормализованную структуру? Ну будет 2,3 - сколько надо csv файлов с ключам.  В конце концов передавать записи для SQL... В нормализованной форме

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, тут вопрос удобства. Вот есть html страница без скриптов, как аналогия xml. Страница представляет собой дерево со множеством узлов и произвольной вложенностью. В json такое еще можно переконвертировать, а вот в виде csv это уже будет какое-то безумное месиво.

Answer (score 1):

Файлы * .csv всегда имеют множество проблем: когда разделители столбцов, границы столбцов, невидимые символы, такие как нулевые терминаторы \ 0, и разрывы строк CrLf находятся в середине фактических данных.

Самый надежный формат для перемещения данных - XML.

XML имеет следующие стандарты w3c, поддерживаемые API:

(1) XQuery

(2) XPath

(3) XSL:

(3.1) XSLT

(3.2) XSL-FO

(4) XSD (1.0 and 1.1)

(5) LINQ to XML

(6) etc.